# Decorate a symbol depending on the context

Tags: macros

I have the following macro defining a mathematical symbol:

```
\newcommand{\myX}[2]{x_{#1}^{#2}}
```

Depending on the context, the symbol x should be decorated with a `\widetilde` or a `\widehat` or stay undecorated.

A pseudocode could look like:

```
\hatcontext
Hello $\myX{1}{2}$ % x has a hat
\tildecontext
Hello $\myX{1}{2}$ % x has a tilde
\nodecoratorcontext
Hello $\myX{1}{2}$ % x is undecorated
```

I have already defined the macros for many of those symbols, and I also use them in my text (with no decorators at all), so a solution that doesn't need too much change in the text and in the macros would be great.

**What's the best practice to achieve that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by “context” you mean an environment, it's just a matter of defining correctly the macro:

```
\newenvironment{decotilde}{\let\decorate\widetilde}{}
\newenvironment{decohat}{\let\decorate\widehat}{}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{deconone}{\let\decorate\@firstofone}{}
\newcommand\decorate{\@firstofone} % default
\makeatother

% now we can define macros based on \decorate
\newcommand{\myX}[2]{\decorate{x}_{#1}^{#2}}
```

If you prefer a declarative style like in your example:

```
\newcommand{\hatcontext}{\let\decorate\widehat}
\newcommand{\tildecontext}{\let\decorate\widetilde}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nodecoratorcontext}{\let\decorate\@firstofone}
\makeatother

\nodecoratorcontext % start up with no decoration

% now we can define macros based on \decorate
\newcommand{\myX}[2]{\decorate{x}_{#1}^{#2}}
```

What’s the purpose of `\@firstofone`? It simply removes the braces, because its definition is basically

```
\newcommand\@firstofone[1]{#1}
```

so, when this is the value for `\decorate`, from `\myX{a}{b}` you first get

```
\decorate{x}_{a}^{b}
```

and then

```
x_{a}^{b}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems nice. What I don not understand: What's the purpose of \@firstofone? I can not quite find a good explanation.

Comment: While it works basically, it seems to make trouble when done inside the argument of another macro. Is that possible? I'm currently trying to understand it better, but it's not easy with LaTeX...

Comment: @Michael What do you mean? I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. Anyway, context depending macros are *evil*. Use `\tilde` when you want a tilde, `\hat` when you want a hat.

Answer (score 0):

```
\def\hatcontext{\def\myX##1##2{\hat{x}_{##1}^{##2}}}
\def\tildecontext{\def\myX##1##2{\tilde{x}_{##1}^{##2}}}
\def\nodecoratorcontext{\def\myX##1##2{x_{##1}^{##2}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now use the following solution, comments are welcome:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{decotilde}{%
\renewcommand{\decorateme}[1]{\widetilde{##1}}
\BODY
}

\NewEnviron{decohat}{%
\renewcommand{\decorateme}[1]{\widehat{##1}}
\BODY
}

\NewEnviron{deconone}{%
\renewcommand{\decorateme}[1]{##1}
\BODY
}

\begin{document}

 \newcommand{\decorateme}[1]{#1}
 \newcommand{\mya}{\decorateme{a}}

 \begin{deconone}
  It's $\mya$.
 \end{deconone}

 \begin{decohat}
  It's $\mya$.
 \end{decohat}

 \begin{decotilde}
  It's $\mya$.
 \end{decotilde}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\NewEnviron`?

Comment: @egreg: I'm mostly a beginner, so I just searched how to create an own environment, and that's what I found. Would there be a better solution?

Comment: Yes: `\newenvironment` is the key; `\NewEnviron` is a rather advanced tool, which can bite you in several ways. But see my other approach.